# How to set Image Source in C# to XAML Static Resource programmatically?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, staticresource

I have this `ResourceDictionary` in `Main.xaml`:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <BitmapImage x:Key="Customer" UriSource="Icons/customer.png"/>
        <BitmapImage x:Key="Project" UriSource="Icons/project.png"/>
        <BitmapImage x:Key="Task" UriSource="Icons/task.png"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

I initially set the image using:

```
<Image Name="TypeIcon" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"
    Source="{StaticResource Customer}" Height="16" Width="16"/>
```

I'm trying to change `TypeIcon`'s `Source` from *Customer* to *Project* in a C# method.

I've tried using:

```
TypeIcon.Source = "{StaticResource Project}";
```

But I get this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type `string` to `System.Windows.Media.ImageSource`

I've tried defining the image using `new ImageSource()`, but this doesn't work either.

How can I change the image's `Source` programmatically in C#?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After much Googling, whilst writing this question, I figured out how to do it:

```
TypeIcon.Source = (ImageSource) Resources["Project"];
```

Comment: What is what here? For "ImageSource" you also need to include "using System.Windows.Media;". But "Resources" is still not available in current context...

Answer (score 11):

It is not for static resources but perhaps will be useful anyway... :)

i.e. how to set background for Grid dynamically

```
var myBrush = new ImageBrush();
            var image = new Image
                            {
                                Source = new BitmapImage(
                                    new Uri(
                                        "pack://application:,,,/YourAppName;component/Images/Boo.png"))
                            };
myBrush.ImageSource = image.Source;
MainGrid.Background = myBrush;
```

i.e. how to set icon of the app dynamically

```
var idleIco = new Image
            {
                Source = new BitmapImage(
                    new Uri(
                        "pack://application:,,,/YourAppName;component/Images/idle.ico"))
            };
SomeObjectYouAreUsingToSet.IconSource =idleIco.Source;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `ImageSourceConverter` class to get what you want, for example:

```
img1.Source = (ImageSource)new ImageSourceConverter().ConvertFromString("/Assets/check.png");
```

Comment: The `Media` namespace is unavailable for universal apps `System.Windows.Media.ImageSourceConverter`